# Json.NET implicit casting

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this code :

```
class Sometype
{
    public Number pos { get; set; }
}

class Number
{
    private uint num;

    private Number(uint num)
    {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public static implicit operator uint(Number sid)
    {
        return sid.num;
    }

    public static implicit operator Number(uint id)
    {
        return new Number(id);
    }
}
```

And this json : `{"pos":123}`

When I try to deserialize this, I get a JsonException `Error converting value 123 to type 'Tester2.Program+Number'.`. Please advise me.

Comment: Have you tried `public static implicit operator Number(string id)
    {
        return new Number(uint.Parse(id));
    }`?

Comment: I don't quite understand how that would work. In the json, `123` *is* a number.

Comment: Yes, it is a number.  But if for any reason the JsonType thinks it is a string this would be a very quick and easy check.

Comment: Tried it. Same error.

Comment: Figured it was worth a shot.  But did (hopefully) post a good answer for you below.

Comment: The answers below may help to deserialize, but in my case I want to be able to serialize the object as well. For an answer that solves that take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472404/json-net-how-to-serialize-object-as-value

Answer (score 3):

If you add an `implicit` (or `explicit`) conversion from `long` to `Number`, this will work fine.

JSON.NET works with `long`s when dealing with integral types, not `uint`s, and so your cast from `uint` is never called. For example:

```
class Number
{
    private uint num;

    private Number(uint num)
    {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public static implicit operator Number(uint id)
    {
        return new Number(id);
    }

    public static implicit operator Number(long id)
    {
        return new Number((uint)id);
    }

    public static implicit operator uint(Number sid)
    {
        return sid.num;
    }
}
```

Obviously this could result in overflow errors, so be careful. Another solution would be to create a custom converter to handle this (might be worth looking into if you're serializing and deserializing this type).

**Here's a working example**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MP4E3N

Answer (score 0):

Full source for Console app/Any CPU is below.  If this doesn't work for you change the declaration of pos to be of type object and then do `pos.GetType()` to see what you are actually getting if not an Int64.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


class Sometype
{
    public Number pos { get; set; }
}

class Number
{
    private uint num;

    private Number(uint num)
    {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public static implicit operator uint(Number sid)
    {
        return sid.num;
    }

    public static implicit operator Number(Int64 id)
    {
        return new Number((uint)id);
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Sometype thing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sometype>("{\"pos\":123}");
    }
}
```