# Customise NewtonSoft.Json for Value Object serialisation

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Sometimes, perhaps in a DDD situation, you might want to use C# to create Value Objects to represent data, to give more meaning to your domain than using primitive types would, with the added benefit of being immutable.

For example:

```
public class PostalCode // Bit like a zipcode
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public PostalCode(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    // Maybe sprinkle some ToString()/Equals() overrides here
}
```

Bravo. Well done me.

The only thing is, when serialised to Json, you get this:

```
{
    "Value": "W1 AJX"
}
```

That sort of looks okay, but when it's used as a property of an object (let's say an address) then it looks like this:

```
{
  "Line1": "Line1",
  "Line2": "Line2",
  "Line3": "Line3",
  "Town": "Town",
  "County": "County",
  "PostalCode": {
    "Value": "W1 AJX"
  }
}
```

Taken to an extreme, you can see there's a lot of noise here. What I'd like to do, is tell Newtonsoft.Json, that when it sees a type of `PostalCode`, that it can serialise it to a string value (and vice versa). That would result in the following json:

```
{
  "Line1": "Line1",
  "Line2": "Line2",
  "Line3": "Line3",
  "Town": "Town",
  "County": "County",
  "PostalCode": "W1 AJX"
}
```

Is this achievable? I've had a look through the docs and I suspect a custom `JsonConverter` might be the way forward?

Comment: I answered in the "duplicate" question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48005782/442459. I don't believe these questions are completely the same. But the answer has a generic way to solve the issue.

Comment: See also my answer in the "duplicate" question, using reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333106/20444

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PostalCode // Bit like a zipcode
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PostalCode")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    // Maybe sprinkle some ToString()/Equals() overrides here
}
```

I think this is your answer?

Comment: It's a good answer, certainly. Although I would rather avoid sprinkling json.net attributes over classes that, technically speaking, are unaware of such things as serialisation. Attributes used like this are basically a leaky abstraction, though I appreciate the simplicity of this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Could you leverage the `implicit operator` syntax?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

```
public class PostalCode
{
     public string Value { get; private set; }

     public PostalCode(string value)
     {
         this.Value = value;
     }

     public static implicit operator string(PostalCode result)
     {
         return result.Value;
     }
 }


var postCode = new PostalCode("WN11 2PZ");
Console.Output(postCode);  // "WN11 2PZ"
```

I haven't tested this so I could be way off!

Comment: How does this change the behavior of the Newtonsoft JSON serializer?

Comment: It doesn't, but it may cause the serializer to return the post code string rather than a new object.