# How to create a generic JsonConverter for Value Object serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design, system.text.json, value-objects

I'm storing domain objects as JSON in the database. To store DDD value objects I need to create a `JsonConverter`. I'm trying to create a generic value object converter in `System.Text.Json`.

I have seen the following related questions in SO and `EventFlow` implementation :

- [Json.net how to serialize object as
  value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472404/json-net-how-to-serialize-object-as-value/48005782#48005782)
- [Customise NewtonSoft.Json for Value Object
  serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780979/customise-newtonsoft-json-for-value-object-serialisation)
- [SingleValueObjectConverter](https://github.com/eventflow/EventFlow/blob/develop-v0/Source/EventFlow/ValueObjects/SingleValueObjectConverter.cs) - This looks good but only applicable for `SingleValueObject`

So how to create a generic value object `JsonConverter` in `System.Text.Json` without having a performance penalty.

**Edit:**
To add some context, this is the entity:

```
public class Meeting : Entity
{
    public MeetingId Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set;}
    private MeetingTerm Term { get; private set;}
    ... // other properties
}

public class MeetingTerm : ValueObject
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; }
    ... // other properties
}

public class MeetingId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    ... // other properties
}
```

I want to serialize it as:

```
{
    "id": "unique-guid",
    "title": "foo",
    "startDate": "foo",
    "endDate": "bar"
    ... // other properties
}
```

Comment: _"To store DDD value objects I need to create a JsonConverter"_ Why is that? Isn't the System.Text.Json API already generic? Why do you need some `JsonConverter`? And why do you have links related to Json.NET?

Comment: @GuruStron I have updated the question with an example, hope that helps to answer your queries.

Comment: So, you might as well build a new model that takes a `Meeting` instance as input and extracts *some* of the property values of its objects. Or do you want a to build a method / Converter, that takes **all** the property values and objects from `Meeting` and returns all property values (discarding the objects) as a new, single, object?

Comment: Can you confirm that what you want to do for a class derived from `ValueObject` is to bubble all of it serializable properties up to the container object?  If so, there's no easy way to do that with `System.Text.Json` as it [does not provide access to its internal serialization contract information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182)...

Comment: So you will basically have to write your own serializer.  And if you don't want a performance penalty that means doing something like compiling your own expressions. I don't really recommend it as it's a lot of work, but to get started you could look at [Custom JSON serializer for optional property with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431434/3744182).

Comment: @Jimi I'm looking for a converter.

Comment: @dbc Yes, the class derived from ValueObject is to bubble all of it serializable properties up to the container object. You can see `SingleValueObjectConverter` which does the same but only for a single property.