# Writing a custom JsonConverter for Value Objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a generic ValueObject class like this one

```
public abstract class ValueObject : 
    IEquatable<ValueObject>, 
    IComparable, 
    IComparable<ValueObject> {

    protected abstract IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents();
}
```

this class does not have any property. To implement a value object I can then create any new class like the following

```
public sealed class PersonName : ValueObject {

    private PersonName(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
        MiddleName = middleName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public static PersonName Create(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName) {
        //Validate input and create object
        return new PersonName(firstName, middleName, lastName);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents() {
        yield return FirstName;
        yield return MiddleName;
        yield return LastName;
    }
}
```

Please note that

- object has a single private constructor
- properties have private setters
- object creation happens through a single `Create` static method

I am struggling with json serialization and deserialization using Newtonsoft.Json. I have also tried to understand the logic behind [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48005782/23137927) and the [original source code](https://github.com/eventflow/EventFlow/blob/develop-v1/Source/EventFlow/ValueObjects/SingleValueObjectConverter.cs) referenced by it.

What I am trying to achieve is how to make a generic JsonConverter that, compared to the one showd in the linked answer, will be able to

- get the static Create method
- use that method to construct the object during deserialization mapping the parameters by name.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I am ok with serialization using value objects inside any other class for example when using in a class like this

```
public class Individual {
    public PersonName Name { get; }
    public string Citizenship { get; }
}
```

I am able to serialize json like this

```
{
    "$type":"Entities.Individual, myassembly",
    "name":{
        "$type":"ValueObjects.PersonName, myassembly",
        "firstName": "John",
        "middleName": "",
        "lastName": "Wayne"
    },
    "citizenship": "American"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than a custom `JsonConverter`, you can write a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that looks for a static `Create()` method inside objects inheriting from `ValueObject` and assigns a delegate invoking it to [`JsonObjectContract.OverrideCreator`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_OverrideCreator.htm).  Having done so, the static method will be invoked in place of a normal constructor.

To do this, first create the following contract resolver:

```
public class ValueObjectResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    const string CreateMethodName = "Create";

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (typeof(ValueObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            try
            {
                var createMethod = objectType.GetMethod(CreateMethodName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
                if (createMethod != null)
                {
                    contract.OverrideCreator = (args) => createMethod.Invoke(null, args) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"null created object {objectType.Name}");
                    contract.CreatorParameters.Clear();
                    foreach (var param in CreateStaticConstructorParameters(createMethod, contract.Properties))
                        contract.CreatorParameters.Add(param);
                }
            }
            catch (AmbiguousMatchException ex)
            {
                // TODO: Handle multiple Create() methods with dfferent argument lists however you want.
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        return contract;
    }

    JsonPropertyCollection CreateStaticConstructorParameters(MethodInfo createMethod, JsonPropertyCollection memberProperties)
    {
        // Adapted from https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L743
        // By https://github.com/JamesNK/
        // License: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/LICENSE.md
        var parameterCollection = new JsonPropertyCollection(createMethod.DeclaringType!);
        foreach (var parameterInfo in createMethod.GetParameters().Where(i => i.Name != null))
        {
            var matchingMemberProperty = MatchProperty(memberProperties, parameterInfo.Name, parameterInfo.ParameterType);
            if (CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter(matchingMemberProperty, parameterInfo) is {} property)
                parameterCollection.AddProperty(property);
        }
        return parameterCollection;
    }

    static JsonProperty? MatchProperty(JsonPropertyCollection properties, string? name, Type type)
    {
        if (name == null)
            return null;
        var property = properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(name);
        // must match type as well as name
        if (property?.PropertyType == type)
            return property;
        return null;
    }       
}
```

To use it, cache an instance statically somewhere as recommended by the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver):

```
public static DefaultContractResolver Resolver { get; } = new ValueObjectResolver()
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(),
};
```

And now you will be able to round-trip data models containing `ValueObject` like so:

```
Individual individual1 = new()
{
    Name = PersonName.Create("John", "", "Wayne"),
    Citizenship = "American",
};

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new()
{
    ContractResolver = Resolver,
    // Add other settings as required.
    // TODO, CAUTION -- If you use TypeNameHandling you should write a custom serialization binder for security reasons.
    // See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_typenamehandling.htm
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(individual1, Formatting.Indented, settings);

var individual2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Individual>(json, settings);
```

Notes:

- For simplicity I simply call [`MethodInfo.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke) directly.  If performance becomes an issue you could use reflection to manufacture a delegate.
- C# [record types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/records) also support *value-based equality*.  You might consider whether you could use them instead of inventing something similar.
- I notice you are using `TypeNameHandling`.  Please be aware that there are security risks associated with this setting. As explained in the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_typenamehandling.htm):

  > TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializationBinder.htm) when deserializing with a value other than None.

  For details see *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954)* and *[External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49038055)*.
- The resolver assumes that each `ValueObject` subtype has only one `Create()` method.  If you ever introduce value objects with multiple `Create()` methods you will have to update `CreateObjectContract()` accordingly, e.g. by selecting the `Create()` method with the largest number of parameters.
- See *[JSON.net ContractResolver vs. JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41088492)* for guidance when to use a custom converter vs. when to use a custom resolver.  In practice, custom resolvers tend to play better with `TypeNameHandling` and with reference preservation.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dfd2VO).

Comment: Thanks very much for the the drafted solution and the guidance! I wrote a few unit tests, more to come, and didn't found any problem now. One small question is: can you please elaborate more on the first bullet, the alternative to Invoke I mean. I can't vote up the question because of reputation but I would have done more than once :)

Comment: @user23137927 - if calling `MethodInfo.Invoke()` directly each time becomes a performance bottleneck (you can check this by profiling), you can write reflection code to generate a delegate in runtime.  That delegate can be saved in `contract.OverrideCreator` instead of my simple one which does `createMethod.Invoke(null, args)`.  There are two common ways to do this, using either  `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` or `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Compile()`.  But the code is complex either way so you may not want to do it unless you have an actual performance bug.

Comment: @user23137927 - to get started, see e.g. [MethodInfo.Invoke performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10313979) or [Making reflection fly and exploring delegates](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) or Newtonsoft's [ExpressionReflectionDelegateFactory](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ExpressionReflectionDelegateFactory.cs).  It's also possible to generate delegates using `System.Reflection.Emit` but this is extremely complicated so I don't recommend it unless necessary.

Comment: Just curious if, in case of using the native serializer, that is `System.Text.Json`, you would go along the same concept or would change approach

Comment: @user23137927 - At first glance as of .NET 8 System.Text.Json would be much harder.  System.Text.Json exposes [`JsonTypeInfo<T>.CreateObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinfo-1.createobject?view=net-7.0) but it is **parameterless**.  There does not seem to be a way inject a customized parameterized creation factory.  And System.Text.Json still does not support populating a root object so something like Json.NET's `CustomCreationConverter<T>` is not possible either.